# Reuse UIViews (In Variable size) in UIScrollView in Both Direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, reusability

In my application I have large number of UIView in a UIScrollView. UIScrollView can scroll in both direction. UIViews are in different in size. The Problem is when I am loading all views total memory like 350 MB. In Oder to reduce memory load I want to load the UIViews dynamically with in the Visible area of my UIScrollView and reuse the view objects while scrolling for loading next or previous views like UITableView or UICollectionView.

Please suggest How I will proceed .

Comment: use a collectionview..

Comment: Or use a tableview!!

Comment: I can't use collection view or Table view as they has unidirectional scroll and my views are not identical in size .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a collectionview as peko wrote, but if you really want to use a scrollview I think that you should be able to do something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    for (UIView *yourView in yourArrayWithViews) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > yourView.frame.origin.y + yourView.frame.size.height){
            Remove your view.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Collection view can't be scroll in both direction. I have added my requirement specifically here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053971/uiscrollview-which-can-be-scroll-in-both-direction-for-large-number-of-views-wit